# Three.js group rendering

Tags: javascript, three.js, rendering

I am trying to render a group of objects with three.js using a single function that takes the object to be rendered as a parameter (render2, line 35), but it is not working. I can make a single cube rotate as long as there is a function built for controlling only that cube, but I get an error when I try to use the render2 function. The cubes made from the cubeGenerator function seem to match what goes into the groupRenderer function, which also matches what initially goes into the render2 function. After that, the render and render1 functions print the cube and cube1 information as expected, but the render2 function prints out a number and an error:

```
main.js:20 T…E.Mesh {uuid: "6902A0C3-7CFA-4B5C-A7BC-11259CE69113", name: "", type: "Mesh", parent: T…E.Scene, children: Array[0]…}
main.js:28 T…E.Mesh {uuid: "275129EB-BD99-4156-B208-CED6F49F6112", name: "", type: "Mesh", parent: T…E.Scene, children: Array[0]…}
main.js:36 408.2339999877149
main.js:38 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined
```

I went through the "Intro to WebGL with Three.js" tutorial at http://threejs.org/ and it worked just fine until I tried playing around with it. cube and cube1 are working, but the group of cubes display on the screen and do not rotate. I appreciate any help. Here is the code I have right now:

```
Line    Code
1   var scene = new THREE.Scene();
2   var aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
3   var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, aspect, 0.1, 1000);
4   var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
5   renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
6   document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
7   camera.position.z = 10;
8
9   var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
10  var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
11  var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
12  cube.position.x = -1;
13
14  var geometry1 = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
15  var material1 = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
16  var cube1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry1, material1);
17  cube1.position.x = 1;
18
19  var render = function() {
20      console.log(cube);
21      requestAnimationFrame(render);
22      cube.rotation.x += 0.05;
23      cube.rotation.y += 0.05;
24      renderer.render(scene, camera);
25  };
26
27  var render1 = function() {
28      console.log(cube1);
29      requestAnimationFrame(render1);
30      cube1.rotation.x += 0.05;
31      cube1.rotation.y += 0.05;
32      renderer.render(scene, camera);
33  }
34
35  var render2 = function(object) {
36      console.log(object);
37      requestAnimationFrame(render2);
38      object.rotation.x += 0.05;
39      object.rotation.y += 0.05;
40      renderer.render(scene, camera);
41  }
42
43  var cubeGenerator = function(newGroup) {
44      console.log("--------------------\nGenerating Cubes");
45      for (var i = -2; i < 2; i++) {
46      var newGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
47      var newMaterial = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
48      var newCube = new THREE.Mesh(newGeometry, newMaterial);
49      newCube.position.x = i;
50      newGroup.add(newCube);
51      console.log(newCube);
52      }
53      console.log("Done Generating Cubes\n--------------------");
54  };
55
56  var groupRenderer = function(renderGroup) {
57      console.log("--------------------\nRendering Group");
58      for (object of group.children) {
59      console.log(object);
60      render2(object);
61      }
62      console.log("Done Rendering Group\n--------------------");
63  };
64
65  var group = new THREE.Group();
66  cubeGenerator(group);
67
68  scene.add(cube);
69  scene.add(cube1);
70  scene.add(group);
71  render();
72  render1();
73  groupRenderer(group);
```

I tried this modification, but it also didn't work:

```
Line    Code
43  var cubeGenerator = function(newGroup) {
44      console.log("--------------------\nGenerating Cubes");
45      for (var i = -2; i < 2; i++) {
46      // var newGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
47      // var newMaterial = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
48      // var newCube = new THREE.Mesh(newGeometry, newMaterial);
49      // newCube.position.x = i;
50      // newGroup.add(newCube);
51      // console.log(newCube);
52      var clone = cube.clone();
53      clone.position.x = i;
54      newGroup.add(clone);
55      console.log(clone);
56      }
57      console.log("Done Generating Cubes\n--------------------");
58  };
```

Note:
The tutorial doesn't always show up at the threejs.org website, but it should come up by refreshing the page or navigating away and back to it. You might need to try multiple times.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do but.... you first call `render()` and inside that call `requestAnimationFrame(render)`, so this function will continuously be called. Then you do the same in `render1` and `render2`. AFAIK this means that all 3 functions will be called every frame.

Comment: If you do not want this, remove the calls to `requestAnimationFrame`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This accomplishes what I wanted:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, aspect, 0.1, 1000);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
camera.position.z = 10;

var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
cube.position.x = -1;

var geometry1 = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
var material1 = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
var cube1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry1, material1);
cube1.position.x = 1;

var render = function() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    cube.rotation.x += 0.05;
    cube.rotation.y += 0.05;
    cube1.rotation.x += 0.05;
    cube1.rotation.y += 0.05;
    for (object of group.children) {
    object.rotation.x += 0.05;
    object.rotation.y += 0.05;
    }
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

var cubeGenerator = function(newGroup) {
    console.log("--------------------\nGenerating Cubes");
    for (var i = -2; i < 3; i++) {
    var newGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
    var newMaterial = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
    var newCube = new THREE.Mesh(newGeometry, newMaterial);
    newCube.position.x = i;
    newGroup.add(newCube);
    console.log(newCube);
    }
    console.log("Done Generating Cubes\n--------------------");
};

var group = new THREE.Group();
cubeGenerator(group);

scene.add(cube);
scene.add(cube1);
scene.add(group);
render();
```

I combined the three render functions into one that render each of the objects. @dcromley I think your solution would cause my group of objects to rotate as if they were one segmented object, but what I wanted was for a group of objects to rotate in the same way, but separate from each other (ie. five cubes, each rotating  around their own center rather than five cubes rotating around the center of the middle cube). Maybe I am mistaken, though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to render only once.  If you want rotate an object your routine would be:

rotate1(object1);

If you want a group of objects to rotate together, add the objects to a scene (and add the scene to your base scene) and rotate the scene.  Your routine would be:

rotate2(scene1);

EDIT: script added

```
  "use strict";
var renderer, scene, camera, light, geometry, material, mesh;
var scene2, mesh1, mesh2, mesh3, mesh4;
window.onload = function() {
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer(); 
  renderer.setSize(750, 750); 
  renderer.setClearColor( 0x102030, 1);  
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  scene = new THREE.Scene(); // the base scene
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(30, 1);
  camera.position.set(0, 0, 30);
  camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));
  light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x444444);
  scene.add(light); 
  light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xff8888, 1);
  light.position.set(10, 10, 20);
  scene.add(light);
  light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0x88ff88, 1);
  light.position.set(-10, 10, 20);
  scene.add(light);

  mesh1 = makebox(-3, -3, 0); // a couple of individual objects
  scene.add(mesh1);
  mesh2 = makebox(-3,  3, 0);
  scene.add(mesh2);

  scene2 = new THREE.Scene(); // a sub-scene, the boxes on the right
  mesh3 = makebox( 0, -3, 0);
  scene2.add(mesh3);
  mesh4 = makebox( 0,  3, 0);
  scene2.add(mesh4);
  scene2.position.set(3, 0, 0);
  scene.add(scene2);

  fnloop();
}
function fnloop() {
  mesh1.rotateY(.01); // individual object
  scene2.rotateY(-.01); // scene of 2 objects
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(fnloop);   
}
function makebox(x, y, z) {
  geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 2, 3);
  material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color:0xffffff, wireframe:false } );
  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  mesh.position.set(x, y, z);
  return mesh;
}
```

Comment: @2pha - I'll bet you 15 points that he will like this model (with a sub-scene).

Comment: You may be right. I'm still not sure what the OP really wants